# Facebook commenting w/Rails 4 and Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm having trouble adding Facebook social plugins (specifically commenting) to my Rails 4 app with Turbolinks enabled.  I followed the example on [turbolinks issue #62](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/62), but couldn't get it to work.

I also tried turbolink's solution [here](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html), but couldn't get it to work.

Fixing the apparent typo on the turbolinks page per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18112911/1839944) did not work either.

The SDK isn't loading and there are no errors in the console.

Code:

```
### view:
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= request.original_url %>"></div>

### coffeescript:
fb_root = null
fb_events_bound = false

$ ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless fb_events_bound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB.XFBML.parse()
    )
  fb_events_bound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  fb_root = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length > 0
    $('#fb-root').replaceWith fb_root
  else
    $('body').append fb_root

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  window.fbAsyncInit = initializeFacebookSDK
  $.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1")

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    appId     : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    channelUrl: '//www.mydomain.com/channel.html'
    status    : true
    cookie    : true
    xfbml     : true

### /public/channel.html
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

--

Thanks.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works...

create a `social.js.coffee` in `assets/javascripts` folder.

in it write:

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That has it semi-working. On first visit to a page, comments aren't shown, however.  Hitting submit doesn't append the new comment to the list of comments either.  Although, this might be an unrelated issue. After refreshing the page, everything appears as expected. Also, doesn't that solution initialize the SDK on every page load/change - getting expensive as the app grows?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Install observejs:

```
gem 'observejs'
```

Then add tag to the widget:

```
<div as="FB" class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= request.original_url %>"></div>
```

Then create a new script in javascripts folder (fb.coffee in my example):

```
ObserveJS.bind 'FB', class
  root: document.createElement('div')
  @::root.id = 'fb-root'

  loaded: =>
    if !document.body.contains(@root)
      document.body.appendChild(@root)

    if FB?
      FB.XFBML.parse()
    else
      @initialize()

  initialize: =>
    js = document.createElement('script')

    script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
    js = document.createElement('script')
    js.id = 'facebook-jssdk'
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID&version=VERSION_OF_API"
    script.parentNode.insertBefore(js, script)
```

Include the js files in your application.js

```
//= require observejs
//= require fb
```